# Add downstream task to every task without downstream in a DAG in Airflow 1.9

Tags: airflow

**Problem**: I've been trying to find a way to get tasks from a DAG that have no downstream tasks following them.

**Why I need it**: I'm building an "on success" notification for DAGs. Airflow DAGs have an `on_success_callback` argument, but problem with that is that it gets triggered after *every task* success instead of just DAG. I've seen other people approach this problem by creating notification task and appending it to the end. Problem I have with this approach is that many DAGs we're using have multiple ends, and some are auto-generated.

Making sure that all ends are caught manually is tedious.

I've spent hours digging for a way to access data I need to build this.

**Sample DAG setup**:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from datetime import datetime

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 7, 29)}

dag = DAG(
    'append_to_end',
    description='append a tast to all tasks without downstream',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval='* * * * *',
    catchup=False)

task_1 = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task_1')
task_2 = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task_2')
task_3 = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='task_3')

task_1 >> task_2
task_1 >> task_3
```

This produces following DAG:

[image: DAG with two ending tasks]

**What I want to achieve** is an automated way to include a new task to a DAG that connects to all ends, like in an image below.

[image: DAG with new task appended to both ending tasks]

Comment: Depending on the need you might want to check out the current code. If I am not mistaken Airflow 1.10 adds a few options on the DAG level for e.g. successful runs.

Comment: Sadly I'll have to wait until 1.10 is properly released (it's in rc2 now I believe?) until I can test that, but thanks for a good pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's an old post, but I've had a similar need as the above posted.
You can add to your return function a statement that doesn't return your "final_task" id, and so it won't be added to the get_leaf_task return, something like:

```
def get_leaf_tasks(dag):
    return [task for task_id, task in dag.task_dict.items() if len(task.downstream_list) == 0 and task_ids != 'final_task']
```

Additionally, you can change this part:

```
for task in leaf_tasks:
    task >> final_task
```

to:

```
get_leaf_tasks(dag) >> final_task
```

Since it already gives you a list of task instances and the bitwise operator ">>" will do the loop for you.

Comment: In this setup, I would pass the `final_task` as an argument to be excluded to allow more flexibility on what this final task can be, but your answer does the trick.

Comment: Ideally it would be a best option if you'd pass the task ids to the function, as to being more reusable than my code you're right. 
Could be something like: 

def get_leaf_tasks(dag,task_ids):
   return [task for task_id, task in dag.task_dict.items() if len(task.downstream_list) == 0 and task_ids not in task_ids]

Answer (score 0):

What I've got to so far is code below:

```
def get_leaf_tasks(dag):
    return [task for task_id, task in dag.task_dict.items() if len(task.downstream_list) == 0]

leaf_tasks = get_leaf_tasks(dag)
final_task = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id='final_task')

for task in leaf_tasks:
    task >> final_task
```

It produces the result I want, but what I don't like about this solution is that `get_leaf_tasks` must be executed before `final_task` is created, or it will be included in `leaf_tasks` list and I'll have to find ways to exclude it.

I could wrap assignment in another function:

```
def append_to_end(dag, task):
    leaf_tasks = get_leaf_tasks(dag)
    dag.add_task(task)

    for task in leaf_tasks:
        task >> final_task

final_task = DummyOperator(task_id='final_task')
append_to_end(dag, final_task)
```

This is not ideal either, as caller must ensure they've created a `final_task` without DAG assigned to it.